# One react component shows up instead of the intended one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Right now I'm having a problem with my application. What the application does is, simply navigate to another page on a button press, or play a sound and navigate to another page at the press of a button. As I was working on in it, I encountered a problem that I have no idea how to solve. It is showing one a component even when it isn't called. For instance when I press a button that says All which the address is localhost:3000/All and it should show the All.js component. However it is showing a completely different component that is found in localhost:3000/Stop/Nt. I initially thought this was a routing issue, but I can't find where it may be going wrong. I'll post below the Nt page of what is showing, vs. what is supposed to show up. Below is my router, I'm thinking something went wrong there....

Misbehaving button

```
          <Button 
          className={classes.buttonStyles} 
          variant="outlined" 
          color="primary"
          startIcon={<Avatar src={'https://i.redd.it/w3kr4m2fi3111.png'} />}
          component={RouterLink}
          to="/All"
          >All
          </Button>
```

App.js (Router)

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import React from "react"
import Home from "./Home"
import Eat from "./Eat/Eat"
import Condiment from "./Eat/Condiment"
import Dairy from "./Eat/Dairy"
import Fruit from "./Eat/Fruit"
import Meals from "./Eat/Meals"
import Meat from "./Eat/Meat"
import Snack from "./Eat/Snack"
import Vegetables from "./Eat/Vegetables"
import Play from "./Play/Play"
import Games from "./Play/Games"
import Lose from "./Play/Lose"
import Skip from "./Play/Skip"
import Slide from "./Play/Slide"
import Swing from "./Play/Swing"
import Toy from "./Play/Toy"
import Win from "./Play/Win"
import Match from "./Play/Match"
import Party from "./Play/Party"
import Difficult from"./Play/Difficult"
import He from "./Pronouns/He"
import I from "./Pronouns/I"
import It from "./Pronouns/It"
import Me from "./Pronouns/Me"
import My from "./Pronouns/My"
import She from "./Pronouns/She"
import Them from "./Pronouns/Them"
import Us from "./Pronouns/Us"
import We from "./Pronouns/We"
import You from "./Pronouns/You"
import Drink from "./Drink/Drink"
import Want from "./Want/Want"
import WantNt from "./Want/Nt"
import Time from "./Time/Time"
import TimeTime from "./Time/TimeTime"
import Calendar from "./Time/Calendar"
import TDate from "./Time/TDate"
import TimeNt from "./Time/TimeNt"
import Good from "./Good/Good"
import Great from "./Good/Great"
import Wonderful from "./Good/Wonderful"
import Bad from "./Bad/Bad"
import In from "./In/In"
import Not from "./Not/Not"
import Done from "./Done/Done"
import End from "./End/End"
import Direct from "./End/Direct"
import US from "./End/US"
import Work from "./Work/Work"
import And from "./And/And"
import That from "./That/That"
import There from "./There/There"
import Spell from "./Spell/Spell"
import Am from "./Am/Am"
import AmNt from "./Am/Nt"
import Watch from "./Watch/Watch"
import Read from "./Read/Read"
import ReadNt from "./Read/Nt"
import Material from "./Read/Material"
import Like from "./Like/Like"
import Do from "./Do/Do"
import DoNt from "./Do/Nt"
import Catch from "./Do/Catch"
import Dig from "./Do/Dig"
import Fold from "./Do/Fold"
import Hold from "./Do/Hold"
import Lay from "./Do/Lay"
import Pass from "./Do/Pass"
import Pick from "./Do/Pick"
import Point from "./Do/Point"
import Pull from "./Do/Pull"
import Push from "./Do/Push"
import Remember from "./Do/Remember"
import Roll from "./Do/Roll"
import Rough from "./Do/Rough"
import Smooth from "./Do/Smooth"
import Soft from "./Do/Soft"
import Throw from "./Do/Throw"
import Touch from "./Do/Touch"
import Wave from "./Do/Wave"
import Wrap from "./Do/Wrap"
import Find from "./Find/Find"
import Go from "./Go/Go"
import GoNt from "./Go/Nt"
import Building from "./Go/Building"
import Get from "./Get/Get"
import Help from "./Help/Help"
import Look from "./Look/Look"
import Talk from "./Talk/Talk"
import Think from "./Think/Think"
import Hear from "./Hear/Hear"
import Make from "./Make/Make"
import Need from "./Need/Need"
import Turn from "./Turn/Turn"
import Stop from "./Stop/Stop"
import StopNt from "./Stop/Nt"
import Fast from "./Fast/Fast"
import Slow from "./Slow/Slow"
import Love from "./Love/Love"
import New from "./New/New"
import Have from "./Have/Have"
import HaveNt from "./Have/Nt"
import Pay from "./Have/Pay"
import Actual from "./Have/Actual"
import Check from "./Have/Check"
import Cheap from "./Have/Cheap"
import Expensive from "./Have/Expensive"
import Own from "./Have/Own"
import Buy from "./Have/Buy" 
import Shop from "./Have/Shop"
import Inexpensive from "./Have/Inexpensive"
import Cost from "./Have/Cost"
import Change from "./Have/Change"
import Feel from "./Feel/Feel"
import All from "./All/All"
import AllNt from "./All/AllNt"
import Come from "./Come/Come"
import Color from "./Color/Color"
import Right from "./Right/Right"
import RightNt from "./Right/Nt"
import Said from "./Said/Said"
import Follow from "./Follow/Follow"
import Baby from "./Follow/Baby"
import People from "./Follow/People"
import Strange from "./Follow/Strange"
import Ride from "./Ride/Ride"
import Put from "./Put/Put"
import Wear from "./Wear/Wear"
import WearNt from "./Wear/Nt"
import Clothing from "./Wear/Clothing"
import WButton from "./Wear/WButton"
import Dress from "./Wear/Dress"
import Loose from "./Wear/Loose"
import Tie from "./Wear/Tie"
import Tight from "./Wear/Tight"
import Zip from "./Wear/Zip"
import Sit from "./Sit/Sit"
import Body from "./Body/Body"
import Left from "./Left/Left"
import Who from "./Who/Who"
import What from "./What/What"
import When from "./When/When"
import Where from "./Where/Where"
import Why from "./Why/Why"
import Count from "./Count/Count"
import Add from "./Count/Add"
import Subtract from "./Count/Subtract"
import Multiply from "./Count/Multiply"
import Divide from "./Count/Divide"
import Please from "./Please/Please"
import Shapes from "./Shapes/Shapes"
import Numbers from "./Numbers/Numbers"
import Letters from "./Letters/Letters"
import Weather from "./Weather/Weather"
import Animal from "./Animal/Animal"
import Template from "./template"
import Big from "./Big/Big"
import Strong from "./Big/Strong"
import Thick from "./Big/Thick"
import Heavy from "./Big/Heavy"
import Lift from "./Big/Lift"
import Drop from "./Big/Drop"
import Fat from "./Big/Fat"
import Powerful from "./Big/Powerful"
import BigNt from "./Big/Nt"
import Ask from "./Ask/Ask"
import Little from "./Little/Little"
import Weak from "./Little/Weak"
import Skinny from "./Little/Skinny"
import Thin from "./Little/Thin"

function App() {

  return (

    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/Template" component={Template}/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/In" component={In}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big" component={Big}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Strong" component={Strong}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Thick" component={Thick}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Heavy" component={Heavy}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Lift" component={Lift}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Drop" component={Drop}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Fat" component={Fat}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Powerful" component={Powerful}/>
          <Route exact path="/Big/Nt" component={BigNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Little" component={Little}/>
          <Route exact path="/Little/Weak" component={Weak}/>
          <Route exact path="/Little/Skinny" component={Skinny}/>
          <Route exact path="/Little/Thin" component={Thin}/>
          <Route exact path="/Ask" component={Ask}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat" component={Eat}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat/Condiment" component={Condiment}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat/Dairy" component={Dairy}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat/Fruit" component={Fruit}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat/Meals" component={Meals}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat/Meat" component={Meat}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat/Snack" component={Snack}/>
          <Route exact path="/Eat/Vegetables" component={Vegetables}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play" component={Play}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Difficult" component={Difficult}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Games" component={Games}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Lose" component={Lose}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Match" component={Match}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Party" component={Party}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Skip" component={Skip}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Side" component={Slide}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Swing" component={Swing}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Toy" component={Toy}/>
          <Route exact path="/Play/Win" component={Win}/>
          <Route exact path="/He" component={He}/>
          <Route exact path="/I" component={I}/>
          <Route exact path="/It" component={It}/>
          <Route exact path="/Me" component={Me}/>
          <Route exact path="/My" component={My}/>
          <Route exact path="/She" component={She}/>
          <Route exact path="/Them" component={Them}/>
          <Route exact path="/Us" component={Us}/>
          <Route exact path="/We" component={We}/>
          <Route exact path="/You" component={You}/>
          <Route exact path="/Drink" component={Drink}/>
          <Route exact path="/Want" component={Want}/>
          <Route exact path="/Want/Nt" component={WantNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Time" component={Time}/>
          <Route exact path="/Time/TimeTime" component={TimeTime}/>
          <Route exact path="/Time/Calendar" component={Calendar}/>
          <Route exact path="/Time/TDate" component={TDate}/>
          <Route exact path="/Time/TimeNt" component={TimeNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Good" component={Good}/>
          <Route exact path="/Good/Great" component={Great}/>
          <Route exact path="/Good/Wonderful" component={Wonderful}/>
          <Route exact path="/Bad" component={Bad}/>
          <Route exact path="/Not" component={Not}/>
          <Route exact path="/Done" component={Done}/>
          <Route exact path="/End" component={End}/>
          <Route exact path="/End/Direct" component={Direct}/>
          <Route exact path="/End/US" component={US}/>
          <Route exact path="/Work" component={Work}/>
          <Route exact path="/Want" component={Want}/>
          <Route exact path="/And" component={And}/>
          <Route exact path="/That" component={That}/>
          <Route exact path="/There" component={There}/>
          <Route exact path="/Spell" component={Spell}/>
          <Route exact path="/Am" component={Am}/>
          <Route exact path="/Am/Nt" component={AmNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Watch" component={Watch}/>
          <Route exact path="/Read" component={Read}/>
          <Route exact path="/Read/Nt" component={ReadNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Read/Material" component={Material}/>
          <Route exact path="/Like" component={Like}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do" component={Do}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Nt" component={DoNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Catch" component={Catch}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Dig" component={Dig}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Fold" component={Fold}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Hold" component={Hold}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Lay" component={Lay}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Pass" component={Pass}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Pick" component={Pick}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Point" component={Point}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Pull" component={Pull}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Push" component={Push}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Remember" component={Remember}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Roll" component={Roll}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Rough" component={Rough}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Smooth" component={Smooth}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Soft" component={Soft}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Throw" component={Throw}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Touch" component={Touch}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Wave" component={Wave}/>
          <Route exact path="/Do/Wrap" component={Wrap}/>
          <Route exact path="/Find" component={Find}/>
          <Route exact path="/Go" component={Go}/>
          <Route exact path="/Go/Nt" component={GoNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Go/Building" component={Building}/>
          <Route exact path="/Get" component={Get}/>
          <Route exact path="/Help" component={Help}/>
          <Route exact path="/Look" component={Look}/>
          <Route exact path="/Talk" component={Talk}/>
          <Route exact path="/Think" component={Think}/>
          <Route exact path="/Hear" component={Hear}/>
          <Route exact path="/Make" component={Make}/>
          <Route exact path="/Need" component={Need}/>
          <Route exact path="/Turn" component={Turn}/>
          <Route exact path="/Stop" component={Stop}/>
          <Route exact pat="/Stop/Nt" component={StopNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Slow" component={Slow}/>
          <Route exact path="/Fast" component={Fast}/>
          <Route exact path="/Love" component={Love}/>
          <Route exact path="/Feel" component={Feel}/>
          <Route exact path="/New" component={New}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have" component={Have}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Nt" component={HaveNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Pay" component={Pay}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Actual" component={Actual}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Check" component={Check}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Cheap" component={Cheap}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Expensive" component={Expensive}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Own" component={Own}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Buy" component={Buy}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Shop" component={Shop}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Inexpensive" component={Inexpensive}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Cost" component={Cost}/>
          <Route exact path="/Have/Change" component={Change}/>
          <Route exact path="/All" component={All}/>
          <Route exact path="/All/AllNt" component={AllNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Come" component={Come}/>
          <Route exact path="/Color" component={Color}/>
          <Route exact path="/Right" component={Right}/>
          <Route exact path="/Right/Nt" component={RightNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Said" component={Said}/>
          <Route exact path="/Ride" component={Ride}/>
          <Route exact path="/Put" component={Put}/>
          <Route exact path="/Sit" component={Sit}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear" component={Wear}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/Nt" component={WearNt}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/Clothing" component={Clothing}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/WButton" component={WButton}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/Dress" component={Dress}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/Loose" component={Loose}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/Tie" component={Tie}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/Tight" component={Tight}/>
          <Route exact path="/Wear/Zip" component={Zip}/>
          <Route exact path="/Body" component={Body}/>
          <Route exact path="/Left" component={Left}/>
          <Route exact path="/Who" component={Who}/>
          <Route exact path="/What" component={What}/>
          <Route exact path="/When" component={When}/>
          <Route exact path="/Where" component={Where}/>
          <Route exact path="/Why" component={Why}/>
          <Route exact path="/Count" component={Count}/>
          <Route exact path="/Count/Add" component={Add}/>
          <Route exact path="/Count/Subtract" component={Subtract}/>
          <Route exact path="/Count/Multiply" component={Multiply}/>
          <Route exact path="/Count/Divide" component={Divide}/>
          <Route exact path="/Please" component={Please}/>
          <Route exact path="/Shapes" component={Shapes}/>
          <Route exact path="/Numbers" component={Numbers}/>
          <Route exact path="/Letters" component={Letters}/>
          <Route exact path="/Weather" component={Weather}/>
          <Route exact path="/Animal" component={Animal}/>
          <Route exact path="/Follow" component={Follow}/>
          <Route exact path="/Follow/Baby" component={Baby}/>
          <Route exact path="/Follow/People" component={People}/>
          <Route exact path="/Follow/Strange" component={Strange}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you please confirm component `All` is not a copy of component `StopNt`, e.g., the content are identical, just the file name is different ?

Comment: Yes they are indeed different. There are several other files that are doing the exact same thing. All is different from that of StopNt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you have a spelling mistake here :

```
<Route exact pat="/Stop/Nt" component={StopNt}/>
```

it should be ***path*** not pat.

```
<Route exact path="/Stop/Nt" component={StopNt}/>
```

Comment: That was it. I'm an idiot. Thank you soooo much!!!!!